# How to create a simple script to perform 'Reverse IP Lookup' with a php site

Tags: php, server

How to create/develop a script to perform `reverse IP lookup` like this [Reverse IP Lookup Site](http://viewdns.info/reverseip/?host=72.167.3.128&t=1)
On that site,  there is a free `reverse IP lookup` limit of 1000 and I must pay to get the full report.

I don't care about the column `Last Resolved Date` and I just want to know all the domains that are hosted on same IP.

Comment: There is a linux command nslookup which might get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Check those functions
http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php

I don't know what exactly you want to accomplished but I think this is good start.

Comment: thanks for your response  i just want to know all domain that hosted on 1 IP (shared host/vps/dedicated)  this description on that site "to quickly shows all other domains hosted from the same server. Useful for finding phishing sites or identifying other sites on the same shared hosting server."

Comment: i mean, i just want to quickly shows all other domains hosted from the same server..